# Running a background task involving a third-party service in Django

Tags: django, celery

The use-case is this: we need to pull in data from a third-party service and update the database with fresh records, *every week*. The different ways I have been able to explore have been

- either creating a [custom django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)
- or running a background task using Celery (and probably ELK for logging)

I just want to know which way is more feasible and simpler? And if there's another way that I can explore. What I want is monitoring the task for the first few runs then just relying on the logs.

Comment: Feasability & simplicity are subjective matters, and there are definitely many ways to handle automated processes with regards to a web server - if you have a specific question about a specific tool, that's probably a good fit for Stack Overflow, but I think this is unfortunately too broad for us to help you.

Comment: In your opinion, what is the right place to ask this theoretical question @DavidCain?
I just want to know different ways of running long time-consuming tasks on the server with logging

Comment: I don't have a resource recommendation for you, sorry. All I can tell you is that the Stack Exchange network is geared towards defined problems with specific answers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @AbdussamiTayyab Running a django management command using crontab is simpler than setting up celery. Celery should be used where you want to run a task when a user requests it. In that case, you'll probably want to send some feedback to the user about the task. Celery is suitable for this. Crontab is better for running periodic tasks in the background that don't need any interaction with the user.

Comment: Alright, thanks @xyres

Comment: will keep it in mind from now David, thanks @DavidCain